# Preloaded DVD with Ubuntu

Tags: installation

I currently have no means of downloading Ubuntu onto a DVD disc. Would it be possible for a disc with the latest Ubuntu OS be send to me?
Thanks

Comment: This is the wrong site for such requests.

Comment: Try contacting your nearest [Loco team](http://loco.ubuntu.com/).  Cannonical only sell LTS releases but you may find someone who will make you a DVD or USB stick for a nominal cost (to cover costs and time). Or create your own you only need a PC with either USB or a DVD burner the download is [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately at moment you can only buy 12.04 LTS from Canonical store.

If you decide to buy aforementioned cd, this is the [link](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=976) to follow. price in EU is  £5.04

Back in time there was service shipping free cd called ShipIt but has closed.

Answer (score 0):

Send me your address and I'll burn a DVD and send it to you by postal mail. By the way, do you need a 32 bit version or a 64 bit version? What type of machine do you have? (I ask this because if you have a low resource machine it'd be better to try a lighter version of Ubuntu such as Lubuntu).

Comment: Lap top is 32 bit, Toshiba, Equium A100 - 306, Model PSAABE......Address, 22 Wellesley House, Horton Crescent, Epsom, Surrey, KT19 8BQ England..........I really appreicate you sending me a disc with the OS on it, Thanks –

Comment: I'll send a Lubuntu DVD according to your machine specifications. That's because it'd work better for your type of machine.

Comment: you'll be receiving the disk anytime soon.

Comment: Hi, not sure who was the user that sent me a copy of Lubuntu, received and installed the os :) so far very pleased. Thxs.

Comment: Please could someone explain (in simple terms) where I can find the termainal to  install for following code:for lubuntu-restricted-extras -- sudo apt-get install lubuntu-restricted-extras.....thxs

Comment: I sent it. Glad to know that everything's fine. For the extras open Synaptic and in the search box type "restricted", search for ubuntu-restricted-extras on the results and install it. I prefer them over the lubuntu-restricted-extras (on my opinion and choice they seem to be a little bit more complete).